# How to upload the PDF, XSL and TXT files in Google Drive

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Hi I'm Developing the Android app to upload the file in Google drive, If the user to enter the gmail user id or already android gmail account for selection based on the user selection, How can i achieve the issue,
Please update the issue, Files are created devices itself and that file to directly upload the google drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google's Drive APIs, just follow the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started) and it should work. I am using it for a C# program and it works good.

Umm I see that there are no explanations on how to upload a file. Check [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) link after you complete the authentication and the other stuff in the first link, I think it might help.